# Function to replace repeated code with foreach loop in php (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have the following function:

```
public function grouping(array $cluster)
    {
        $groupingOrders = GroupingOrder::where('cluster_ticket', $cluster['ticket'])->get();

        $ordersGroup = collect($cluster['matrix']['orders'])->groupBy(function($item) {
            return $item['hash'];
        });
        
        $groupHash = $ordersGroup->filter(fn ($orders) => count($orders) > 1);
        $groupLatLong = $ordersGroup->filter(fn ($orders) => count($orders) == 1)
            ->collapse()
            ->groupBy(function($item) {
            return $item['latitude'] . $item['longitude'];
        });
        
        foreach($groupHash as $orders) {
            $groupingOrder = GroupingOrder::create([
                'cluster_ticket' => $cluster['ticket'],
                'volume'         => $orders->sum('volume'),
                'weight'         => $orders->sum('weight'),
            ]);

            foreach($orders as $order){
                $order = Order::create([
                    'grouping_order_id'          => $groupingOrder['id'],
                    'external_id'                => $order['id'],
                    'hash'                       => $order['hash'],
                    'latitude'                   => $order['latitude'],
                    'longitude'                  => $order['longitude'],
                    'volume'                     => $order['volume'],
                    'weight'                     => $order['weight'],
                    'visit_time'                 => $order['visitTime'],
                    'pickup_time'                => $order['timePickup'],
                    'delivery_time'              => $order['timeDelivery'],
                    'minutes_per_order_pickup'   => $order['minutesPerOrderPickup'],
                    'minutes_per_order_delivery' => $order['minutesPerOrderDelivery'],
                    'minutes_per_item_pickup'    => $order['minutesPerItemPickup'],
                    'minutes_per_item_delivery'  => $order['minutesPerItemDelivery'],
                    'time'                       => $order['time'],
                    'risk'                       => $order['risk'],
                ]);
            }
        }

        foreach($groupLatLong as $orders) {
            $groupingOrder = GroupingOrder::create([
                'cluster_ticket' => $cluster['ticket'],
                'volume'         => $orders->sum('volume'),
                'weight'         => $orders->sum('weight'),
            ]);

            foreach($orders as $order){
                $order = Order::create([
                    'grouping_order_id'          => $groupingOrder['id'],
                    'external_id'                => $order['id'],
                    'hash'                       => $order['hash'],
                    'latitude'                   => $order['latitude'],
                    'longitude'                  => $order['longitude'],
                    'volume'                     => $order['volume'],
                    'weight'                     => $order['weight'],
                    'visit_time'                 => $order['visitTime'],
                    'pickup_time'                => $order['timePickup'],
                    'delivery_time'              => $order['timeDelivery'],
                    'minutes_per_order_pickup'   => $order['minutesPerOrderPickup'],
                    'minutes_per_order_delivery' => $order['minutesPerOrderDelivery'],
                    'minutes_per_item_pickup'    => $order['minutesPerItemPickup'],
                    'minutes_per_item_delivery'  => $order['minutesPerItemDelivery'],
                    'time'                       => $order['time'],
                    'risk'                       => $order['risk'],
                ]);
            }
        }

        $ordersTicket = GroupingOrder::with('orders')
            ->where('cluster_ticket', $cluster['ticket'])
            ->get()
            ->map(function($grouping) {
                return [
                    'id'            => $grouping->id,
                    'latitude'      => (float) $grouping->orders->first()->latitude,
                    'longitude'     => (float) $grouping->orders->first()->longitude,
                    'visitTime'     => $grouping->orders->first()->visit_time,
                    'time'          => $grouping->orders->max('time'),
                    'timePickup'    => $grouping->orders->first()->pickup_time,
                    'timeDelivery'  => $grouping->orders->first()->delivery_time,
                    'weight'        => (float) $grouping->weight,
                    'volume'        => (float) $grouping->volume,
                    'risk'          => $grouping->orders->first()->risk,
                ];
            });

        $cluster['matrix']['orders'] = $ordersTicket->toArray();
        
        return $cluster;
    }
```

My problem is I need to think of another function to replace this part of the code that repeats itself:

```
foreach($groupHash as $orders) {
            $groupingOrder = GroupingOrder::create([
                'cluster_ticket' => $cluster['ticket'],
                'volume'         => $orders->sum('volume'),
                'weight'         => $orders->sum('weight'),
            ]);

            foreach($orders as $order){
                $order = Order::create([
                    'grouping_order_id'          => $groupingOrder['id'],
                    'external_id'                => $order['id'],
                    'hash'                       => $order['hash'],
                    'latitude'                   => $order['latitude'],
                    'longitude'                  => $order['longitude'],
                    'volume'                     => $order['volume'],
                    'weight'                     => $order['weight'],
                    'visit_time'                 => $order['visitTime'],
                    'pickup_time'                => $order['timePickup'],
                    'delivery_time'              => $order['timeDelivery'],
                    'minutes_per_order_pickup'   => $order['minutesPerOrderPickup'],
                    'minutes_per_order_delivery' => $order['minutesPerOrderDelivery'],
                    'minutes_per_item_pickup'    => $order['minutesPerItemPickup'],
                    'minutes_per_item_delivery'  => $order['minutesPerItemDelivery'],
                    'time'                       => $order['time'],
                    'risk'                       => $order['risk'],
                ]);
            }
        }

        foreach($groupLatLong as $orders) {
            $groupingOrder = GroupingOrder::create([
                'cluster_ticket' => $cluster['ticket'],
                'volume'         => $orders->sum('volume'),
                'weight'         => $orders->sum('weight'),
            ]);

            foreach($orders as $order){
                $order = Order::create([
                    'grouping_order_id'          => $groupingOrder['id'],
                    'external_id'                => $order['id'],
                    'hash'                       => $order['hash'],
                    'latitude'                   => $order['latitude'],
                    'longitude'                  => $order['longitude'],
                    'volume'                     => $order['volume'],
                    'weight'                     => $order['weight'],
                    'visit_time'                 => $order['visitTime'],
                    'pickup_time'                => $order['timePickup'],
                    'delivery_time'              => $order['timeDelivery'],
                    'minutes_per_order_pickup'   => $order['minutesPerOrderPickup'],
                    'minutes_per_order_delivery' => $order['minutesPerOrderDelivery'],
                    'minutes_per_item_pickup'    => $order['minutesPerItemPickup'],
                    'minutes_per_item_delivery'  => $order['minutesPerItemDelivery'],
                    'time'                       => $order['time'],
                    'risk'                       => $order['risk'],
                ]);
            }
        }
```

I need to create a function that inside of it has the foreach above and then I just call that function instead of the two foreach in the first function of my code.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I haven't tried anything yet because I have no clue of how to create this new function.

Comment: Just copy the repeating code into it's own function and try to run it. When you run it, it will give an error. Fix the error, then try again. Keep doing this until it works. I don't think anyone here is going to do it for you, mostly because we can't without a lot more information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what the hell is going on here. But we can extract duplicated code to a method called `createGroupedOrders`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

public function createGroupedOrders(Collection $orders, $clusterTicket)
{
    $groupingOrder = GroupingOrder::create([
        'cluster_ticket' => $clusterTicket,
        'volume'         => $orders->sum('volume'),
        'weight'         => $orders->sum('weight'),
    ]);

    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        $order = Order::create([
            'grouping_order_id'          => $groupingOrder['id'],
            'external_id'                => $order['id'],
            'hash'                       => $order['hash'],
            'latitude'                   => $order['latitude'],
            'longitude'                  => $order['longitude'],
            'volume'                     => $order['volume'],
            'weight'                     => $order['weight'],
            'visit_time'                 => $order['visitTime'],
            'pickup_time'                => $order['timePickup'],
            'delivery_time'              => $order['timeDelivery'],
            'minutes_per_order_pickup'   => $order['minutesPerOrderPickup'],
            'minutes_per_order_delivery' => $order['minutesPerOrderDelivery'],
            'minutes_per_item_pickup'    => $order['minutesPerItemPickup'],
            'minutes_per_item_delivery'  => $order['minutesPerItemDelivery'],
            'time'                       => $order['time'],
            'risk'                       => $order['risk'],
        ]);
    }
    
}
```

Then:

```
foreach ($groupHash as $orders) {
    $this->createGroupedOrders($orders, $cluster['ticket']);
}

foreach ($groupLatLong as $orders) {
    $this->createGroupedOrders($orders, $cluster['ticket']);
}
```

Comment: That is exactaly what I was expecting. The thing is I'm starting now at a job and I'm still learning, I really don't know much but I'm trying. This will help me a lot!! Thanks Kevin!